# How to determine if a user has not registered to receive push notifications and/or has their settings disabled

Tags: ios, cordova, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

We are sending broadcast push notifications in our hybrid app on MobileFirst 7.1 to the Push.ALL tag.  In the app we have a dialog to display the push notification message via WL.client's onMessage listener.  We do not want this dialog to open, however, when the user has either not registered to receive push notifications at app install, or later modified their settings to disable push notifications for our app.  How can we prevent the onMessage listener from opening the dialog?  The listener is firing when the app is opened even if the user has opted out of receiving push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Push enabled applications automatically subscribe to Push.ALL tag. In case you do not want to ( your user is not registering to push or disables push) , you can unsubscribe from Push.ALL , to prevent broadcast notifications from reaching the specific client.

Use `unsubscribeTag(tagname,options)` API for this.

More details on the API [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.Push.html#unsubscribeTag).

Comment: Thanks Vivin. We're wondering though how the app would know to unsubscribe from the Push.ALL tag.  We want the app to unsubscribe whenever a user either opts out of push notification registration, or later goes to modify their settings and opts out.  What we're looking for is a way to read the device's push notification app-level settings.

Comment: What do you mean by app level settings ? Does this mean if the app is subscribed for push or not? Or push enabled? Does isTagSubscribed() API help?

Comment: App level meaning device settings level.  We want to know if the user has either chosen to NOT register for push notifications for that app when the app was first run (or first run after a re-install).  We also want to know if the user later went into their settings and turned off push notifications for that app.  Our client's ask is that when a user opts out of push notifications for our app through their native os choices, they don't want them to receive any Push.ALL onMessage events either.  The unsubscribe is easy but we need to determine WHEN to unsubscribe.

Comment: isTagSubscribed would just tell us if Push.ALL was subscribed which we've seen gets subscribed to automatically regardless of whether or not the user chose to register for push notifications via the native iOS prompt at first run after installation.